# How to create a AJAX filter in the index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a requirement to create a filter in the index page, I do not have much idea on jQuery/AJAX, please help me in creating the code

```
// index view 
- @results.each do |result|
  %tr   
    %td= result.test.name
    %td= result.status
```

Here is my controller

```
def index       
  @results = Result.all
end
```

Comment: What you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for "SEARCH USING JQUERY".

There is a good tutorial [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax)

First you must create your controller like this:

```
def index
   @products = Product.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
end
```

Then your model:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
   where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
   scoped
  end
end
```

Your index view:

```
<% form_tag products_path, :method => 'get', :id => "products_search" do %>
 <p>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
 </p>
 <div id="products"><%= render 'products' %></div>
<% end %>
```

Javascript view:

```
$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("products")) %>");
```